# Tests with image processing

Tags: node.js, testing, image-processing, mocha.js

I'm currently building an application that will do some image processing using Node.js and OpenCV.

My question is more about testing. Should I include the images in the project itself for testing (that would be about 100Mb), or should I 'enable' deep testing from the command line, and pass in a folder/list-file as parameters of testing?

I'm using Mocha with Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Depend on what purposes you are pursue.

If you need:

- compact sized test environment;
- more flexible tests.

=> Not include images to Test Project.

If you need:

- easy to run tests.

=> Include images to Test Project.